# What's wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Gmail: "Couldn't sign in" error with latest version, but other google apps sync just fine. Older Gmail version works fine](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/142889)

It has 3 answers at the time of composing this post. The content of them are

1.

> This is mostly a cache issue. I have also experienced this previously. Please try these out and let me know
>
> - Download the app and login again. Your issue might be solved
> - Use any cache cleaning software
>
> If the above doesn't work, try the below ones go to sites like [traffic rider apk](https://thetechnologypost.com/traffic-rider-mod-apk/)
>
> If any of the above doesn't work try waiting for the official new update that will probably solve this issue.

2. (this answer is edited more than a month ago to add the 3rd and 4th link, the author also has some reputation on Stack Overflow)

> This is most likely a cache issue. I noticed a number of people having this issue after the latest update. Here are a few things I suggest you try:
>
> 1. Log out of your gmail account in the app and go into the settings.
> 2. In the settings, go into the apps section uninstall the app
> 3. Use any clearning app to clean your junk and phone's cache and restart the phone.
> 4. Download the app again, Try to login again. Hopefully, it should work again.
>
> If this doesn't work then here's another suggestion to test something.
>
> - Go to some Apk sites like [apkpure](https://apkpure.com/) or [Dragon city mod](https://dragongames.co/) and download the older version of the gmail app. Maybe even try [Subway Surfers Apk](https://gamesmodapk.info/subway-surfers-apk/) and [Score Hero game](https://scoreheroapk.live/)
> - Try to run it. If the older version works perfectly then there's problem with the latest update for sure. Just wait for the new one

3.

> Great website. Plenty of helpful info here. I’m sending it to some pals and additionally sharing in delicious. And of course, thank you in your effort! https://games.lol/puzzle/

Even if two of the answers contains information and instructions and therefore "looks like" an attempt to answer the question, I do not understand the appearance of links to random Game Mod Apk sites.

To me, all three are spam, so I flagged two of them as spam, and mod-flagged the last one (#2 above).

The fact that these answers exist seems abnormal for such a regular question, anyone knows what's wrong behind this case?

Comment: Unrelated to the topic, but the OP of 2nd answer [also added spam links on SO on Sep 9 and Sep 27](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31967641/revisions), looks like the account [became suspicious since Sep 9](https://stackexchange.com/users/2834468/blacklotis?tab=activity). At this point, we could salvage that answer (if we want) by removing the spam links.

Comment: @AndrewT. The original revision (i.e. Rev 1) of the 2nd answer also contains the 2nd link (Dragon City Mod Apk is also a fake site, real site [here](http://www.socialpoint.es)). So I think I could have flagged it as spam directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the number of low-quality deleted answers on this question, it's just a question that has been high in Google search results for a long time. Such questions are most likely to attract spam answers because spammers want to attack the pages that get most views, or that show up in searches for their spam keywords.

You'll notice some similarities between the "helpful" content of the spam answers - most likely, both were copied from the same source of generic advice. The third post you quote is the same kind of spam comment you can see on any blog nowadays.